# root to node calculation in a dynamically created tree

Tags: c, dynamic, tree

I am coding in `C`, using `GCC` 4.8.1 as my compiler. The goal is to calculate the sum of products of each path starting from the Trees root node, using the key of the node (no value -- consider it as "item"). The height of Tree and the initial root key are determined by the user (input), where `h` is the height of the tree and `x` is the key of the root node.

To dynamically create the tree, the rules are as follows:

- The Trees root node is `x`.
- If the parent node is `x`, then the children will be `x - 1` (left child), `1` (right child node).
- If the parent node is `x - 1`, then the children will be `x - 1` (left child node) and `1` (right child node).
- If the parent node is `1`, then the children will be `x` (left child node) and `0` (right child node).

**Sample input (and graph to visually represent the rules):** For `h = 3` and `x = 4`.

```
                                           4
                                         /   \
                                       3      1
                                     /  \    / \
                                    3    1  4   0
```

The paths are `4 -> 3 -> 3`, `4 -> 3 -> 1`, `4 -> 1 -> 4` and `4 -> 1 -> 0`.

Moreover, if any node in a given path has a key of `0` then it is not used in the calculation (hence `0` multiplied by any number is `0`). The expected sum is:

`4x3x3 + 4x3x1 + 4x1x4 = 36 + 12 + 16 = 64` (note, `4x1x0` is ignored)

... the question I have is: I am not sure how to implement a dynamic Tree.
here is my code:

```
int n;        //making n(value of root)  global
struct node {
  int data;
  struct node *left,*right;
}
struct node *createnode(int x)
{
  struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
  *n=x;
  if(x==n||x==n-1)
  {
      n->left=createnode(x-1);
      n->right=createnode(1);
  }
  else if(x==1)
  {
      n->left=createnode(x);
      n->right=createnode(0);
  }
  return n;
}
void tree(int x,int y)
{
    struct node *root;
    root=creatnode(x);
}
```

Comment: Where is your attempt to implement this? Show us your work so we can help you -- otherwise why would we put in the effort to help you if you did not put in the effort to help yourself?

Comment: shouldn't the bottom row be 2 1 4 0?

Comment: Improved wording based on my interpretation of the question, fixed typos, rollback or edit if you think I am wrong.

Comment: @JacobPollack i am working on a project and this code is a part of the full program ..actually i am devising a method for solution via permutation.   

 `#include<stdio.h>
int fun(int x,int y,int z)
{if(y==1)
return x;
else
return x-1;
}
int funm(int x,int y,int z)
{
    if(y%2==0)
return 1;
else
return x;
}
int main()
{int s,n,t,k,r,i,j=0,rs[100];
scanf("%d",&t);
while (j<t)
{scanf("%d %d",&n,&k);
i=1;
r=1;
s=1;
while(i<n)
{r*=fun(k,i,n);
s*=funm(k,i,n);
if(n==2||n==3)
s=0;
i++;
}
printf("%d %d\n",r,s);
}
for(j=0;j<t;j++)
printf("%d\n",rs[j]);
return 0;
}`

Comment: @ScottyBauer   yes it is 2 1 4 0 .. that's what i have shown .

Comment: @JacobPollack, sometimes people just need a place to start.

Comment: Hmmm...I see that there was a question about whether the bottom row should be `2 1 4 0`.  Given the definition _'if the parent node is `x - 1`, then the children will be `x - 1` (left child node) and `1` (right child node)'_ seems to mean that the row should be `3 1 4 0`, which is consistent with the 4 paths specified.  If the bottom row should be `2 1 4 0`, then (a) I'd like someone to explain the rule I quoted and how it applies to the subtree with `3` as the parent and either 2 or 3 as the left child and 1 as the right child, and (b) the example path needs to be updated too.

Comment: Incidentally, the rules don't say what the children of a node with 0 should be set to, though at one level it doesn't matter since the path through them won't count.  Also, it isn't clear why there's an emphasis on discarding paths containing a 0; they path can be calculated the same as any other, and the contribution to the result is 0, the same as for any other product where one of the factors is 0.

Answer (score 0):

To start you out, do not worry about the heap or stack or any other memory allocation details.  Rather, understand how to invoke `malloc()` and  `free()`:

```
   // you will need to code struct node ...
   struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

   // populate root node

   // recursively call to create children nodes, etc.

   // invoke a routine to free root and other nodes::
   freenodes(root);
```

You have a lot of work ahead.  But to implement a dynamic tree just use `malloc()`.

Comment: okay so here is my code by now 
`struct node {
int data;
struct node *left,*right;
}
void tree(int x,int y)
{ int i=1;
while(i<x)
{
    struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    i++;

}`  
i know how to traverse a tree but no idea on how to recursively call and generate nodes. some help?

Comment: @Code_reaper have added another answer to help you with this.

Comment: @JackCColeman: you should have edited your original answer, not added a new one.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, I think the person asking the question understands what he and I are doing.

Comment: OK; glad to hear that, but you should still only have one answer to this question, not two.  Also, how does your code initialize the node where the node value is 0?  The current incarnations of `createnode()` that I can see don't handle the case.  I think it likely that both child node pointers should be null pointers, but `createnode()` is using `malloc()`, not `calloc()`, so that isn't guaranteed.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler when the person asking the question has written his code correctly then all concerns will be moot.

Answer (score 0):

per your comment, here is your code:

```
struct node {int data; struct node *left,*right; } 

void tree(int x,int y) {
    int i=1;
    while(i<x) {
       struct node *root = malloc(sizeof(struct node));
       i++;
    }
 }
```

First, of all you only want to create one root node, and to do this recursively you want the root node to create a left child and a right child.  So, now code a routine called `CreateNode(int value)` that: explicitly allocates a node, calls itself to create left and right child nodes returns a pointer to the only node that it explicitly allocated, and instead of the `while` loop, just call it as:

```
 int  have_built_root_node;  // for this problem I would like using this var
                             // but it could also be passed as a parameter!

 int  max_height = 3;

 void tree(int root_value) {
    struct node *root;

    have_built_root_node = 0;
    root = CreateNode(1, root_value);

    }
 }
```

So, CreateNode is going to be your recursive routine, and its logic is important!  So, be careful when you code it!

```
struct node *createnode(int height, int value)
{  struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(struct node));

  // if root node has NOT been built, then build it!
  // set a switch so that its children are NOT created as root nodes.
  // 
  // store this nodes value in n, as *n.value = 
  // test this value as if (*n.value == 
  // compute value for left and right nodes
  // compute height for children nodes, what should happen when
  // the max_height is reached?

  // write code with lots of white space and aligned, it should look pretty!!
  if (x == n|| x == n-1)   // is this syntactically correct?
  {
      n->left  = createnode(x-1);
      n->right = createnode(1);
  }
  else if (x == 1)
  {
    n->left  = createnode(x);
    n->right = createnode(0);
  }
return n;
}
```

Comment: updated my question with the code i am working on..kindly point any errors...i need the final return to the main() to be root node

Comment: First of all, you still need to do a lot of work.  Make any changes to my suggestions as necessary, you understand the problem better than I.  Think about the information needed to create one node, this includes whether you are creating a root node or not.  Finally, every recursive routine needs a condition where it does NOT invoke itself.  This condition occurs at leaf nodes.  So, a tree has: a root; interior nodes (or branches); leaf nodes.  The recursive routine needs to be able to distinguish between these three types of nodes.

Comment: @Code_reaper, have updated my answer with more info.  Go ahead and continue to improve your code.  Overall, we will probably have to go thru about 4 revisions to get code that works, but you will be doing most of the work!!  If you are unable to re-edit the original question then just add another answer or open a new question and let me know about it.

Answer (score 0):

Your current code doesn't take into account the `h` parameter of the tree, so it does not stop the creation process.  You have to take that into account.  The rules you've given for creating the tree are not really complete, either.  You've not defined what happens with a node where the data value is zero.

When developing structures like trees, it is worth having the code to free the structure available, and also a function to print the structure.  The one I've included is a special case version, writing to standard output only (instead of taking a `FILE *` argument), and without a tag to identify the structure being printed.  Normally, my tree dump function would have the signature `void dump_tree(FILE *fp, const char *tag, struct node *tree);`, but it is easy to take the code shown below and generalize it.

#### Code

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/*
** h is the height of the tree and x is the key of the root node.
**
** To dynamically create the tree, the rules are as follows:
**
** - The root node is x.
** - If the parent node is x, then the children will be x - 1 (left), 1 (right).
** - If the parent node is x - 1, then the children will be x - 1 (left) and 1 (right).
** - If the parent node is 1, then the children will be x (left) and 0 (right).
** - If the parent node is 0, then the child pointers will be null.
** - When the nodes are at level h in the tree, the child pointers will be null.
*/

struct node
{
    int          data;
    struct node *left;
    struct node *right;
};

/* Create a tree with value v at with d levels below it with the parameter x */
static struct node *create_node(int x, int d, int v)
{
    struct node *n = malloc(sizeof(*n));
    if (n == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Out of memory\n");
        exit(1);
    }
    n->data = v;
    if (d == 0 || v == 0)
    {
        n->left = 0;
        n->right = 0;
    }
    else if (v == x || v == x - 1)
    {
        n->left = create_node(x, d-1, x-1);
        n->right = create_node(x, d-1, 1);
    }
    else if (v == 1)
    {
        n->left = create_node(x, d-1, x);
        n->right = create_node(x, d-1, 0);
    }
    else
        assert(0);
    return n;
}

static void print_node(struct node *tree)
{
    putchar('(');
    if (tree->left)
        print_node(tree->left);
    printf("[%d]", tree->data);
    if (tree->right)
        print_node(tree->right);
    putchar(')');
}

static void print_tree(struct node *tree)
{
    print_node(tree);
    putchar('\n');
}

static int path_products(struct node *tree)
{
    if (tree->left == 0 && tree->right == 0)
    {
        //printf("Leaf node: %d\n", tree->data);
        return tree->data;
    }
    else
    {
        int lhs = path_products(tree->left);
        int rhs = path_products(tree->right);
        int rv  = tree->data * (lhs + rhs);
        //printf("Interior node: lhs = %d, rhs = %d, data = %d, return %d\n", lhs, rhs, tree->data, rv);
        return rv;
    }
}

static void release_tree(struct node *tree)
{
    if (tree == 0)
        return;
    release_tree(tree->left);
    release_tree(tree->right);
    free(tree);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    if (argc != 3)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Usage: %s height root\n", argv[0]);
        exit(1);
    }
    int h = atoi(argv[1]);
    if (h <= 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid height %s (should be greater than zero)\n", argv[1]);
        exit(1);
    }
    int x = atoi(argv[2]);
    if (x <= 2)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Invalid root value %s (should be greater than two)\n", argv[2]);
        exit(1);
    }
    struct node *tree = create_node(x, h-1, x);

    print_tree(tree);
    printf("Sum of products of paths = %d\n", path_products(tree));
    release_tree(tree);
    return 0;
}
```

#### Sample outputs

```
$ tree 1 4
([4])
H = 1, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 4
$ tree 2 4
(([3])[4]([1]))
H = 2, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 16
$ tree 3 4
((([3])[3]([1]))[4](([4])[1]([0])))
H = 3, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 64
$ tree 4 4 
(((([3])[3]([1]))[3](([4])[1]([0])))[4]((([3])[4]([1]))[1]([0])))
H = 4, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 256
$ tree 5 4
((((([3])[3]([1]))[3](([4])[1]([0])))[3]((([3])[4]([1]))[1]([0])))[4](((([3])[3]([1]))[4](([4])[1]([0])))[1]([0])))
H = 5, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 1024
$ tree 6 4
(((((([3])[3]([1]))[3](([4])[1]([0])))[3]((([3])[4]([1]))[1]([0])))[3](((([3])[3]([1]))[4](([4])[1]([0])))[1]([0])))[4]((((([3])[3]([1]))[3](([4])[1]([0])))[4]((([3])[4]([1]))[1]([0])))[1]([0])))
H = 6, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 4096
$
```

The tree dump format is unambiguous but inscrutable to those unused to it.  Writing a general purpose tree dump that prints it out over multiple lines is a considerably harder proposition to write.

```
$ for j in {3..7}; do for i in {1..5}; do ./tree $i $j; done; done | grep -v '^(' | so
H = 1, X = 3: Sum of products of paths = 3
H = 2, X = 3: Sum of products of paths = 9
H = 3, X = 3: Sum of products of paths = 27
H = 4, X = 3: Sum of products of paths = 81
H = 5, X = 3: Sum of products of paths = 243
H = 1, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 4
H = 2, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 16
H = 3, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 64
H = 4, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 256
H = 5, X = 4: Sum of products of paths = 1024
H = 1, X = 5: Sum of products of paths = 5
H = 2, X = 5: Sum of products of paths = 25
H = 3, X = 5: Sum of products of paths = 125
H = 4, X = 5: Sum of products of paths = 625
H = 5, X = 5: Sum of products of paths = 3125
H = 1, X = 6: Sum of products of paths = 6
H = 2, X = 6: Sum of products of paths = 36
H = 3, X = 6: Sum of products of paths = 216
H = 4, X = 6: Sum of products of paths = 1296
H = 5, X = 6: Sum of products of paths = 7776
H = 1, X = 7: Sum of products of paths = 7
H = 2, X = 7: Sum of products of paths = 49
H = 3, X = 7: Sum of products of paths = 343
H = 4, X = 7: Sum of products of paths = 2401
H = 5, X = 7: Sum of products of paths = 16807
$
```

Comment: This does NOT help the person asking the question.  He should learn to program on his own.